# Will use of volatile impact app's performance in Android?

Tags: java, android, singleton, volatile

I'm trying to make my module instance as singleton. Came across this [article](https://medium.com/@kevalpatel2106/how-to-make-the-perfect-singleton-de6b951dfdb0) where it speaks about various method to achieve singleton instance creation and also touches broken double check locking and ways to avoid this using volatile.

After reading more about volatile, it seems the thread will never cache this variable and would always read from main memory for it's computation. If I implement my singleton using volatile keyword will my app get impacted by performance since it reads from main memory always.

[Image source](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/06/volatile-keyword-java-example-tutorial.html)

Got the following doubts,

1. Where will the thread local memory reside? In which layer would they be L1,L2 or L3 cache?
2. If I implement my singleton using volatile which means that i'm reading from main memory each time - so does this mean that i'm increasing the CPU cycle?
3. Will my app get performance impact if I use this in UI thread?

   [image]

Sample volatile implementation,

```
private static volatile ResourceService resourceInstance;
//lazy Initialiaztion
public static ResourceService getInstance () {
    if (resourceInstance == null) { // first check
        synchronized(ResourceService.class) {
            if (resourceInstance == null) { // double check
                // creating instance of ResourceService for only one time
                resourceInstance = new ResourceService ();                    
            }
        }
    }
    return resourceInstance;
}
```